# switch statement like in R

Tags: r

I want to do a very simple operation in `R` like the following. For example, let's say i have two options as

```
Operation-1:
A=2
B=3
C=A+B
```

and

```
Operation-2
D=4
E=6
F=D+E
```

What I wanted to do is, for example to ask for a keyboard input like `cat("Which operation would you like to execute?")`and then if i insert P1 (for operation-1), then my program executes operation 1 and exits. Is there a simple way of doing this in R (for example using switch statements or in functions)?

PS: The values of `A, B, D` and `E` are **NOT necessarily numeric**. I just use them as numeric to make my sample code easy to understand.

Comment: [Here is the first result of a search for "r user input"](http://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input), you can also see `?readline`, which has an example. So that's how you get user input. What you do with it is up to you, you can use `if` or `switch` or whatever else.

Comment: I will put operation-1 in one function (e.g. function1) and operation-2 in another function (e.g. function2) - and then later i will try to call either function1 or function2 from another function depending on my input.

Comment: Just like the example at the bottom of `?readline`.